# How to show temp data and delete in html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three input box and below one button 
when I click that button I want input data should come into html table and sholud able to delete that record

Kindly help me out
advance thanks

Comment: What you have fired so far? Please post a tidbit of code, you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same with one input box. So making it for three shouldn't be an issue. You must be looking out for this code:

```
$("table").on("click", "tbody tr td a", function () {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  return false;
});
```

You can either press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click on the button to insert temp data. Okay, just heads up, as you didn't put enough code, you can do it this way:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#tempInsert").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
      insertRow();
  });
  $("#tempBtn").click(function () {
    insertRow();
  });
  $("table").on("click", "tbody tr td a", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    return false;
  });
});

function insertRow() {
  if ($("#tempInsert").val().length > 0)
    $("table tbody").append('<tr><td>' + $("#tempInsert").val() + '</td><td><a href="#">&times;</td></tr>');
  $("#tempInsert").val("");
}
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="tempInsert" />
<input type="button" id="tempBtn" value="Add" />
<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="85%">Stuff</th>
      <th width="15%">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
   var input1 = $('#input1').val();
   var input2 = $('#input2').val();
   var input3 = $('#input3').val();
   $('#td1').html(input1);
   $('#td2').html(input2);
   $('#td3').html(input3);
});

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td1"></td>
    <td id="td2"></td>
    <td id="td3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that you are absolutely new and I wrote a simple example for you, just to get the idea of how to do.

**HTML**

```
<table style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px; height: 80px; ">
        <tr>
            <td id="nm"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="fnm"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="ag"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    Name : <input type="text" id="n"><br />
    F/Name: <input type="text" id="fn"><br />
    Age : <input type="text" id="age"><br />
    <button>Click</button>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(event) {
        $('#nm').text($('#n').val());
        $('#fnm').text($('#fn').val());
        $('#ag').text($('#age').val());
        $('#n').val('');
        $('#fn').val('');
        $('#age').val('');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e0gLndf5/)

```js
function Add() {
  var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
  var fname = document.getElementById("FName").value;
  var lname = document.getElementById("LName").value;
  var city = document.getElementById("City").value;
  if (fname == "" && lname == "" && city == "")
    alert("Enter Text in input box");
  else {
    var tblcount = tbl.rows.length;
    var row = tbl.insertRow(tblcount);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = fname;
    cell2.innerHTML = lname;
    cell3.innerHTML = city;
  }
}
```

```css
#tbl tr td {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<input id="FName" type="text"></input>
<input id="LName" type="text"></input>
<input id="City" type="text"></input>
<button id="btnAdd" onclick="Add();">Add</button>

<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td>Fisrt Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>City</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```